# Why can't $cond (aggregation) take only two parameters to become a simple if-statement?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
      count_wanted_group: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                    $and: [{
                        $eq: ["$status", "W"]
                    }]
                }, 1, null]
            }
        },
```

The problem is that I don't want to pass that *null*.
It will generate me something equal to 0. I want it to generate nothing.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```js
{ "$group": {
    "_id": someKey,
    "count_wanted_group": {
        "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": "$status", "W" },
                1,
                0
            ]
        }
    }
}}
```

The [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator is a "ternary" or "if..then..else" construct. You can combine as many logical operators as you want into the "condition" or "if" part such as [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) and [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) or anything that eventually evaluates to a `true/false` assertion.

It's the "then" an "else" parts that matter, and in this case you either want to present `1` as a value to the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operation when the condition is `true` or `0` to the "sum" when the condition is `false`.

That is generally how a "ternary" works.

Answer (score 2):

The [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) aggregation operator requires all three arguments as mentioned in the MongoDB Docs.

There is a workaround for this issue, using the [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.REMOVE) variable, available since MongoDB 3.6. It allows for the conditional exclusion of fields. [See here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#remove-example) for an example from the Mongo reference manual.

For your question,

```
{
    $group: {
        // _id: <expression>, // Group By Expression
        count_wanted_group: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [
                    { $eq: ["$status", "W"] },
                    1,
                    "$$REMOVE"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```